# push / present view controller over tab bar Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I try to reproduce the same way to push the screen as in the fb messenger for [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xuHvN.jpg).

My schema: TabController -> NavController-> embedVC-> pushedVC.

The pushedVC must be over tabbar. I don't want to hide it with tabbar.isHidden = true.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to use UIViewController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true on that screen where you need to hide the tab bar.
You can also try to arrange the UITabBarController as child in UINavigationController.
As far as I know (I can be wrong), UITabBarController will not work in the UINavigationController, so sometimes someone uses their custom TabBarController.

Comment: I ignored this function because it doesn't work when I check it in IB or when I add it in viewDid / WillAppear. I don't know why. I just did the test by inserting vcWithoutTabBar.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true in the vcWithTabBar just before pushing to vcWithoutTabBar and it works as desired. Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 3):

**SWIFT 5** (works also on previous versions)

Before pushing the ViewController, set hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true

Example:

```
let viewController = UIViewController()
viewController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true
navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
```

Comment: Thanks man "hidesBottomBarWhenPaused" works like a charm